# Delegating ActiveRecord objects with plain ruby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delegates

I want to be able to have a `TestUser` model specifically for development and test which acts entirely the same as my normal User model, except that it always authenticates.
The key issue here is to have `TestUser` always call class methods on User and look up it's class level instance variables as though it were a normal User, and not do it through `cattr_accessor` i.e.:

```
class User
  class << self
    attr_accessor :foo
  end
end

class TestUser ?< ??
  ??
end

---
User.foo = 'bar'
TestUser.foo => 'bar'
User.new.authenticate?('password') => maybe, runs authentication
TestUser.new.authenticate?(_) => true
```

I know I could do what I want by just extending User in test and development to always authenticated, but I was wondering if it would be possible to do it with that extra class.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a rails or activerecord problem, but what is getting me is that if I delegate #create or #build from TestUser to User, then I'm unable to properly extend the object that is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't waste any time on this, if you aren't going to use it in production.

You have tests that allow you to "always authenticate a user", but why waste time on this nice to have problem, when you could be coding towards your end goal, to get this out faster/stronger/better ... whatever your goal is.

Comment: I tried to detail the generality of this problem in a comment, but you are right, this shouldn't be a show stopper or anything.  I'm just curious how much you can do with delegators and if it's possible to essentially alias out a class.  Probably should have made that my question rather than wrap it up in this weird example.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestUser < User
  def authenticate?
    true
  end
end
```

But *you should really* use tests/rspec if you are just testing your code.

And you can use: `cattr_accessor :foo` for accessing class variables.

Comment: The way you've described is how we have it setup for our unit tests, I was just trying to keep the example simple.  Part of the issue was that I was trying to avoid using cattr_accessor, though I believe this might be a case where it actually makes sense, since I don't really care if foo propagates up or down subclasses.